# Вывод из массива json

Tags: jquery, json

Есть разметка

```
"id":"1",
  "img": "1.jpg",
  "name": "Сырники из творога",
  "time": "~30 минут",
  "ingredients":[
     { "value": "творог","count":"350г"},
     { "value": "творог","count":"350г"},
     { "value": "творог","count":"350г"}
  ]
```

Что бы вывести `name` или к примеру `time`,я пишу `data.name`  `data.time` в `each` в `$.getJSON`

Как получить  `ingredients` пробовал `data.ingredients.value` выдает `undefined`

Comment: попробуй data.ingredients[0].value

Comment: да работает,а как все сразу?

Comment: @zkolya: `for(var i = 0; i < data.ingredients.length; i++) alert(data.ingredients[i].value);`

Comment: var len=data.ingredients.length;for(var i=0;i<len;i++){alert(data.ingredients[i].value);}

Answer (score 1):

Похожую информацию расписывали тут [SoEn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15627934/each-with-nested-array):

```
$.each(myArray.songs, function (i, ob) {
    $.each(ob, function (ind, obj) {
        console.log("key:" + ind + " value:" + obj);
    });
});
```

PSL(C)

И тут [SoEn 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487841/jquery-parse-json-multidimensional-array):

```
var forum = json.forum;

for (var i = 0; i < forum.length; i++) {
    var object = forum[i];
    for (property in object) {
        var value = object[property];
        alert(property + "=" + value); // This alerts "id=1", "created=2010-03-19", etc..
    }
}
```

BalusC(С)

Да и много где еще...